# Configure Liferay 7.0 and WIldfly with Oracle

Tags: database, oracle11g, wildfly-10, liferay-7

I have a doubt regarding LIferay 7.0 and Wildfly. I recently found a method to integrate Oracle DB with Liferay but, at least in the example and on my attempts to try it, when I start Wildfly with Liferay it keeps telling me "Unsupported Database Oracle".

The tutorial I followed was this one: https://www.dontesta.it/blog/en/2016/04/13/liferay-7-ce-how-to-add-support-for-oracle-db/

Is that only supported for Tomact? (Like in the example in that tutorial).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste exception/error log?

Comment: Please don't use external resources as main parts of a question or answer here on stackoverflow. The external resources may disappear. And your post is harder to find for others with the same problem. Instead you should add the relevant parts to your question and keep the URL as reference.

Comment: I didn't follow your tutorial, but I always configure the datasource in Wildfly and set `jdbc.default.jndi.name` in _portal-ext.properties_ accordingly. Works quite well for Oracle and some other databases.

Comment: Thanks for the link to my tutorial. Were you able to resolve? Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle driver for Liferay 7 CE also works for the bundle with wildfly.
The procedure is very simple:

1. Build the Oracle Driver for Liferay (by following the guide [liferay-portal-oracledb-support](https://github.com/amusarra/liferay-portal-oracledb-support))
2. Download [JDBC Oracle driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html)
3. Copy JDBC Driver in $LIFERA_HOME/wildfly-10.0.0/modules/com/liferay/portal/main/
4. Add JDBC Driver ojdbc7.jar as resource in module.xml ($LIFERA_HOME/wildfly-10.0.0/modules/com/liferay/portal/main/)
5. Copy jar (liferay-portal-oracledb-support-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) of the Oracle Driver for Liferay in $LIFERAY_HOME/wildfly-10.0.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/
6. Start Liferay

By following the above steps you should be able to install successfully Liferay 7, also you can see this tutorial [Liferay 7 Wildfly: How to add support for Oracle DB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fojCjko7Ac)

Answer (score 0):

I point out the project https://github.com/amusarra/liferay-portal-database-all-in-one-support which groups the support for the three commercial databases for versions 7.0, 7.1 and 7.2 of Liferay.

This project add support to the Oracle Database, SQL Server and IBM DB2 database. Liferay has performed refactorting the code so that it is possible and easy to add support for databases no longer supported OOTB (out-of-the-box). The last version (1.1.4) of the driver works with the Liferay 7.2.1 CE GA2.

You can download the latest version binary jar from Maven Central Repository liferay-portal-database-all-in-one-support (https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cit.dontesta), by doing so you can avoid doing the build.

I invite you to read the article How to build a Docker Liferay 7.2 image with the Oracle Database support (https://www.dontesta.it/en/2019/08/21/how-to-build-a-docker-liferay-7-2-image-with-the-oracle-database-support/) which may be interesting for you.